# laravel belongstomany same table Not unique table/alias

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

laravel belongstomany same table error: Not unique table/alias. Help me please.

```
class Categories extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'parent_id',
        'slug',
        'title',
        'description'
    ];

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Categories::class, 'categories', 'id', 'parent_id' );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the wrong type of relationship for a parent/child. You'll need to define `public function parent() { return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id'); }` and `public function children() { return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id'); }`. If you want a Category to have more than 1, or shared parent/child, then you'll need a separate pivot table with `category_a_id` and `category_b_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Without second table you can have many-to-many relationship. You may try one-to-many with something like this:

```php
class Categories extends Model
{
    /* ... */

    public function parentCategory() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'parent_id' );
    }

    public function subCategories() {
        return $this->hasMany( Categories::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```